# Leyenda y colormaps de Matplotlib desde DataFrame de pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bucles, matplotlib

Estoy intentando hacer unas gráficas con Python. En concreto estoy trabajando con dataframes. Me gustaria saber como puedo hacer lo siguiente:

1. Adaptar la leyenda de la gráfica a su correspondiente columna (he visto algo de hacer un diccionario etc...) A modo de ejemplo os pongo el código con 4 DataFrames y 4 columnas cada uno (pero en realidad yo tendría mas columnas y filas).
2. Adaptar colormaps en funcion del nombre de la columna. Por ejemplo, si las columnas contienen AA y BB utilizar un colormaps, y si tienen CC o DD utilizar otro colormap.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   import pylab as plt

   def Plots():
       labels_df1 = list(df1.columns.values)
       labels_df2 = list(df2.columns.values)
       labels_df3 = list(df3.columns.values)
       labels_df4 = list(df4.columns.values)

       fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

       axs[0, 0].plot(df1, df1, label=labels_df1)
       axs[0, 0].set_xlabel('X axis')
       axs[0, 0].set_ylabel('Y axis')
       axs[0, 0].grid(True, which='both')
       axs[0, 0].legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

       axs[0, 1].plot(df1, df2, label=labels_df2)
       axs[0, 1].set_xlabel('X axis')
       axs[0, 1].set_ylabel('Y axis')
       axs[0, 1].grid(True, which='both')
       axs[0, 1].legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

       axs[1, 0].plot(df1, df3, label=labels_df3)
       axs[1, 0].set_xlabel('X axis')
       axs[1, 0].set_ylabel('Y axis')
       axs[1, 0].grid(True, which='both')
       axs[1, 0].legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

       axs[1, 1].plot(df1,  df4, label=labels_df4)
       axs[1, 1].set_xlabel('X axis')
       axs[1, 1].set_ylabel('Y axis')
       axs[1, 1].grid(True, which='both')
       axs[1, 1].legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

       plt.show()


   df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])
   df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])
   df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])

   Plots()
   ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Como qué resultado esperas?

Comment: Espero obtener una leyenda en la que cada label sea un color. Azul AA, naranja BB etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar las columnas de tu dataframe como "labels" se `xticks()` (o `yticks()`). Este método requiere una manera de indice y una lista con los valores. Ejemplo de uso:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('csv.csv')
plt.xticks(range(len(df.columns.values)),df.columns.values)
```

En este ejemplo se usa el atributo `values`, del atributo `columns` del dataframe para conseguir el nombre de las columnas. En este caso `range(len(df.columns.values))` sirve como la manera de indexar los ticks.

Por otro lado, la leyenda de un gráfico se define automáticamente cuando se plotean los dos ejes requeridos (*x* y *y*). En este caso se hace `plot()` de el dataframe en general, por lo tanto es requerido usar un parámetro. Si se usa el mismo valor de las columnas del datraframe, se conseguirá una leyenda con esos valores (para cada columna):

```
plt.legend(df.columns.values)
```

**¿Cómo se aplica esto?**

Dicho lo anterior hay que realizar estas dos modificaciones antes de hacer `show()`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])

plt.xticks(range(len(df.columns.values)),df.columns.values)
plt.plot(df)
plt.legend(df.columns.values)
plt.show()
```

El código anterior resulta así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo se definirías los ticks verticales?**

Solo basta con cambiar el método `xticks()` por `yticks()`:

```
plt.yticks(range(len(df.columns.values)),df.columns.values)
```

Ya con todo lo anterior sabrás como aplicarlo a tu proyecto.

**Enlaces a la documentación oficial de la librería que te pueden servir:**

- [Método `xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#:%7E:text=A%20list%20of%20Text%20objects.&text=Calling%20this%20function%20with%20no,set_xticklabels%20on%20the%20current%20axes.)
- [Método `legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

Espero te haya servido, saludos.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ¡Problema resuelto y muy buena explicación!